# Sum the max of each element index in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I have two lists

```
task=[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5]
hours=[1,7,6,2,3,6,5,2,4,6]
```

-.suppose the value in index are 1,2,3,4,5 without diplicated. I want to. sum (the max of first four index in hours (because number 1 repeated 4 times in task), the max of 5,6 index in hours(because number 2 repeated 2 times in task), the max of 7 index in hours, the max of 8 index in hours, the max of 9,10 index in hours).
.
.
So I need to find the sum of max each value in task with it index in hours

Comment: Could you give an example what the result should look like for your sample data?

Comment: Sure
the output will be: The project can be finished in 26 days.
26 come from max first four index [1,7,6,2] . max 5,6 index [3,6]. max 7 index[5]. max 8 index[2]. max 9,10 index[4,6]. and then sum the results of max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary/Dataframe from your lists and group by task and aggregate to sum:

```py
import pandas as pd
task=[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5]
hours=[1,7,6,2,3,6,5,2,4,6]
df = pd.DataFrame({'task': task, 'hours': hours})
print(df.groupby('task').agg(sum))
```

Output:

```
      hours
task       
1        16
2         9
3         5
4         2
5        10
```

###### Edit: Seems that I misunderstood the question.

You can use the same logic to find max values and then sum them:

```
max_val = df.groupby('task').agg(max)
print(int(max_val.sum()))
```

Output:

```
# max_val:
      hours
task       
1         7
2         6
3         5
4         2
5         6
# sum : 26
```

Comment: I need only max value then the sum of it

Comment: thanks it's right. but if there're another solution without (import pandas as pd)
because I didn't study and maybe loss marks due to this.

Comment: @NoUce so you are asking us to solve **your** task that you get _marks_ for without even attempting to solve it?

Comment: @PatrickArtner is right, we're willing to help but it only makes sense if you want to learn yourself. We can help you with a classical approach. Try to loop through `task` with [`enumerate`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/enumerate-in-python) this might help you to start

Comment: @PatrickArtner No, I solved most of the program but I couldn't understand this idea !

Comment: @Tranbi  I solved can you check if this true please?

#create empty lists
g=[]
h=[]
j=[]
m=[]
k=[]
x=[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5]
z=[1,7,6,2,3,6,5,2,4,6]
#fill the empty lists
for i in range(10):
    if x[i]==1:
        g.append(z[i])
    if x[i]==2:
        h.append(z[i])
    if x[i]==3:
        j.append(z[i])
    if x[i]==4:
        m.append(z[i])
    if x[i]==5:
        k.append(z[i])
#find the maximum for lists
g=max(g)
h=max(h)
j=max(j)
m=max(m)
k=max(k)
print(g,h,j,m,k)
#find the sum
ll=g+h+j+m+k
print(ll)

Comment: This will only work for values from one to 5. Have you learned slicing yet? You could go through x and mark indexes with same values (from `idx_start` to `idx_stop` for example) then find `max(z[idx_start:idx_stop]`